# Problemas con instalación de pyqt5 con pip: "command '/usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1"

Tags: linux, pyqt5, pip, gcc, spyder

Estoy tratando de instalar *Spyder* y tengo problemas con
*PyQt5*. Es la única dependencia que me los ha dado. He buscado
información sobre como solucionar esto pero la verdad, no me ha
ilustrado mucho.

Si alguien me puede explicar a que se debe este error
y cómo solucionarlo se lo agradecería mucho.

Estoy utilizando de python 3.7.3 en una distribución linux x86.

```
    (entorno_virtual) Distopico@mx:~
        $ pip3 install pyqt5==5.15.0
        Collecting pyqt5==5.15.0
          Using cached PyQt5-5.15.0.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
          Installing build dependencies ... error
          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
          
          × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
          │ exit code: 1
          ╰─> [43 lines of output]
              Collecting sip<7,>=5.3
                Using cached sip-6.5.0.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
                Installing build dependencies: started
                Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
                Getting requirements to build wheel: started
                Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
                Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
                Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
              Collecting PyQt-builder<2,>=1.1.0
                Using cached PyQt_builder-1.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 MB)
              Collecting packaging
                Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
              Collecting setuptools
                Using cached setuptools-60.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (953 kB)
              Collecting toml
                Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
              Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
                Using cached pyparsing-3.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
              Building wheels for collected packages: sip
                Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml): started
                Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml): still running...
                Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
                error: subprocess-exited-with-error
              
                × Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
                │ exit code: 1
                ╰─> [10 lines of output]
                    running bdist_wheel
                    running build
                    running build_py
                    running build_ext
                    building 'sipbuild.code_generator' extension
                    code_generator/pybinding.c:30:10: fatal error: Python.h: No existe el fichero o el directorio
                     #include <Python.h>
                              ^~~~~~~~~~
                    compilation terminated.
                    error: command '/usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
                    [end of output]
              
                note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
                ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
              Failed to build sip
              ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
              [end of output]
          
          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
        
        × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully
    
    > .
    
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> See above for output.
        
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Aquí el resto de dependencias que instalé sin problemas:

> applaunchservices==0.1.7 atomicwrites==1.2.0 chardet
> cloudpickle==0.5.0  cookiecutter==1.6.0 diff-match-patch==20181111
> intervaltree==3.0.2 ipython==7.6.0 jedi==0.17.2 jellyfish
> jsonschema==3.2.0 keyring==17.0.0 nbconvert==4.0 numpydoc==0.6.0
> paramiko==2.4.0 parso==0.7.0 pexpect==4.4.0 pickleshare  psutil==5.3
> pygments==2.0 pylint==2.5.0 python-lsp-server==1.3.3
> python-lsp-black==1.0.0 pyls-spyder==0.4.0 pyxdg==0.26 pyzmq==17
> qdarkstyle==3.0.2 qstylizer==0.1.10 qtawesome==1.0.2 qtconsole==5.2.1
> qtpy==1.5.0 rtree==0.9.7 setuptools==49.6.0 sphinx spyder-kernels
> textdistance==4.2.0 three-merge==0.1.1 watchdog==0.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error parece indicar un problema en la compilación. Intenta actualizar o instalar `gcc` y paquetes esenciales para compilación en el sistema. En Debian o sistemas derivados sería algo como:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt update gcc

sudo apt install build-essential

sudo apt upgrade
```

Instala paquetes `python-dev`. Asumiendo una distribución Debian o sistemas derivados de Debian:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev
```

Comment: Si, comprendí que tenía que instalar el paquete de build-essential y algunos más luego de realizar la pregunta.Aun así,continuaba sin poder instalar pyqt5 5.15.6 por pip...al parecer había una dependencia que solo estaba disponible para sistemas Linux de 64 bits y para win de 32 y 64 bits..por lo que tuve que buscar la versión 5.15.2 que no la necesitaba.Por lo que descargue el código fuente de pyqt5 y sip,lo compile en el entorno virtual y funciono.Talvez los más molesto con respecto a la instalación del este ide,es lo poco claro que son con el tema de las dependencias que necesitarás..

Comment: @Boston: qué bueno saber que has resuelto el problema. Aveces es difícil saber cuáles dependencias son necesarias si la documentación no es muy específica.

Comment: Concuerdo,es todo un tema.. gracias por la mano.

Answer (score 0):

Intentan actualizando "pip":

```sh
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Ref. [Can't Download PyQt5 on Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287884/cant-download-pyqt5-on-python)